# Change Name of Datamember dynamically in C#

Tags: c#, datamember, name-attribute

I want Name of Datamember to be displayed dynamically

```
public class SampleDTO
{

      [DataMember]
      public int Time1 { get; set; }
    
      [DataMember]
      public int Time2 { get; set; }
}
```

**For example,**

**Time1** value entered by user = 20,
Name of **Time1** property should be displayed like **“Case > 20 (mins)”**

If **Time1** value entered by user = 15,
Name of **Time1** property should be displayed like **“Case > 15 (mins)”**

How can I do this? Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Displayed *where*? Frankly, this seems like a UI problem, which should be as simple as updating the displayed text on some UI element, but which has *nothing whatsoever* to do with the DTO

Comment: `DataMember` says that the property is used for data binding. It says *nothing* about how it should be displayed. That's the job of the `Display` attribute. Attributes are *static8 though. If you want value comparisons and dynamic labels, you'll have to modify the UI. Even the `Display` attribute doesn't work by itself. The UI controls inspect this and use its (static) value as a label

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'd argue that `DataMember` says that it is used for *serialization*, i.e. storage/persistence - not data binding in the UI sense (it is, after all, `System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute`)